# How get data with redis using this hash

Tags: database, nosql, redis

In the documentation is said that you can use hash to store objects or any kind of data, and later you can extract them. I want to save, for instance, ids from a few users by using hash, and later extract all the ids, or all the elements with ids (something, I didnt accomplish nothing similar), can you help me?

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set user:id:1234 "content of my first user"
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set user:id:1235 "content of my second user"
OK 
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set user:id:1236 "content of my third user"
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> get user:id
(nil)  ####I hoped to see all my id's users listed, I want to make 
       something like that,in the documentation I saw an example, but 
       is not completed####
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are plain top-level key sets. To make a hash, you should use HSET

```
hset user:id 1234 "content of my first user"
hset user:id 1235 "content of my second user"

hgetall user:id
```

Comment: thank you!, really the documentation is very basic, redis is not difficult but I've little experience. THanks

Comment: sorry Im trying something like your code, but I've this erros message: 

    redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hset user_deals:id:1234 "first deal"
    (error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command
    redis 127.0.0.1:6379>

Comment: hset takes three parameters, key, field and value. You're passing only two.